# On the distribution of a scaled sum of a Dirchlet random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, dirichlet-distribution

Consider $(X_{1},\dots,X_{K})=X\sim \text{Dir}(\alpha)$ and a vector $v=(v_{1},\dots ,v_{K})\in\mathbb{R}^{K}$.
Is there a parametric density function for the distribution of:
$Xv^{T}=vX^T=\sum^{K}_{i=1}v_{i}X_{i}$ ?

Comment: Yes: you have defined it.  The usual mathematical objects used to designate such a distribution, such as its density, cumulative function, or characteristic function, likely have no closed form expression unless $v$ has special values.